# PostgreSQL Japanese characters encoding issue

Tags: database, postgresql, encoding, character-encoding

for some reason japanese characters are not being stores correctly in my database, on shell is coming up as x1a and in pgadmin just squares.

[image]

[image]

I found out after I was getting constraint violation when inserting records, and then I removed the constrain to let the values be stored and realise the values were not being encoded properly.

> > 13:14:05 - PGS-220000 PostgreSQL error: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "nmscountry_labelja" DETAIL:  Key
> > (slabelja)=(¿¿¿¿¿) already exists. . 13:14:05 - WDB-200001 SQL
> > statement 'INSERT INTO NmsCountry (sIsoA2, sIsoA3, iIsoNum, sLabelISO,
> > sLabelFR, sLabelEN, sLabelDE, sIana, sItu, sLabelJA, sPhoneFormat,
> > sPhoneExit)
>
> VALUES (:#(1)#, :#(2)#, :#(3)#, :#(4)#, :#(5)#, :#(6)#, :#(7)#,
> :#(8)#, :#(9)#, :#(10)#, :#(11)#, :#(12)#)' could not be executed.
>
> INSERT INTO NmsCountry (sIsoA2, sIsoA3, iIsoNum, sLabelISO, sLabelFR,
> sLabelEN, sLabelDE, sIana, sItu, sLabelJA, sPhoneFormat, sPhoneExit)
> Param(0)=AL   Param(1)=ALB   Param(2)=8   Param(3)=ALBANIA
> Param(4)=Albanie   Param(5)=Albania   Param(6)=Albanien   Param(7)=al
> Param(8)=355   Param(9)=アルバニア   Param(10)=   Param(11)=

Comment: The problem must be the application you use to store text in PostgreSQL. For some reason, it stores only the control character with the hexadecimal number 1A instead of the characters you would like.

Comment: What framework/platform/environment do you use to run those INSERT statements? Are they all configured to support UTF-8? (I wouldn't be surprised if the Windows console environment with Cygwin or CMD had issues with UTF-8.)

Comment: The application executing the inserts is an marketing tool called Adobe Campaign. I've never faced this issue as I've deployed it multiple times. the tool allows you to create a unicode database (utf8) and then goes on to executing the sql code, my environment is RHEL8 and PostgreSQL15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be because of wrong database encoding.

To check postgreSQL server encoding run psql then run the following command :

```
postgres=# SHOW SERVER_ENCODING;
```

If it not `UTF8` Then you should change the server encoding using the following steps:

1. Navigate to `path/to/postgtres/bin` and the open the terminal and run the following command to create backup of your database.

```
pg_dump your_database > dump.sql​ -p <port_number>
```

A new file `dump.sql` is created in the directory.

2. Drop your database.

```
dropdb your_database​
```

3. Create new database with the same name of the dropped one and specify the encoding to be `UTF8`.

```
createdb -E utf8 your_database​
```

4. Restore database data from the backup file you previously created.

```
psql your_database < dump.sql​
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

1. Ensure that the character encoding of your database is set correctly to support Japanese characters. The most common encoding for Japanese is UTF-8.
2. If you're inserting from a programming language, make sure the strings containing Japanese characters are encoded as UTF-8 before inserting them into the database. To test this, try inserting a simple Japanese string directly, using an SQL query.
3. Collation settings can also affect how characters are sorted in a database. Ensure that the collation settings for the relevant columns or tables are appropriate for Japanese characters.

Comment: The collation does *not* influence how characters are stored in the database.

Comment: Yeah, my bad. Not even convinced the 3rd idea would even help anyway.

Comment: How about editing the answer to improve it?